# cout for 2D string vector only printing last line

Tags: c++

I'm reading a text file and loading to a `std::vector<std::string> course` and when I attempt to print it based on `course.size()` and `course[i].size` it only prints the last line.

Here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ifstream fin(argv[1]);
    vector<string> course;
    string line;

    while (getline(fin, line)) {
        course.push_back(line);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < course.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < course[i].size(); j++) {
            cout << course[i][j];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Tried maybe the `'\r'` removal by adding:

```
if (!line.empty() && line[line.size() - 1] == '\r') {
    line.erase(line.size() - 1);
}
```

But that just printed out each `[i][j]` per line next to one another.

Data looks like this:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxx
xxx   yyyxxx
xxxXXYYxxyyy
```

Comment: Did you examine (print, debugger) the value of `course.size()` ?

Comment: "But that just printed out each [i][j] per line next to one another." - that would be the expected output, your code doesn't output a newline at any stage

Comment: @M.M That was a typo, it was `\r` not `\n`. When I get rid of the `\r` and then go through the `for` loop to `cout` it outputs the first row, then a space, then the next row, then a space, etc... on the same line; it never newlines. I'm trying to get each `[i][j]` to print where it was when it was read in.

Comment: @DanielJour Yes and its the correct length (excludes `\r` and `\n`). If I add ` << endl;` it prints each `[i][j]` on a newline so I know it has the data. Just not sure why it prints the whole last line by itself when the ` << endl;` is not included.

Comment: The code you posted would not output a space.  It would improve your question to make sure you have posted your exact code, and also post the exact contents of the input file and the output you are getting . (Use copy/paste, don't type it out in case you make another typo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) does **not** add the delimiting character (the newline in your case) to the output string. Thus, none of those `std::string` of your `std::vector<std::string> course` contains a newline. Thus you need to output a newline yourself after writing each of those strings.

Then please note that the inner `for` loop is completely unnecessary. There's an overload/specialization of `operator<<` for `std::string`, thus you can simplify to:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < course.size(); ++i) {
  std::cout << course[i] << std::endl; // or '\n' if you don't need flushing
}
```

---

If you insist on the inner loop:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < course.size(); i++) {
    for (std::size_t j = 0; j < course[i].size(); j++) {
        std::cout << course[i][j];
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

[Live in action.](http://ideone.com/Nk8XZ3)

Comment: Good to know, and that definitely works, but what if I was wanting to print a 2D vector of `int` or `char`? Why did the two `for` loops not print `[0][1][0][2]...[0][k]`?

Comment: Beyond that, using those `for` loops I can print each individual element of the vector on a `newline`, curious why I cant print them in their original positions.